# Оформление прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

Вроде бы, никогда это не вызывало у меня проблем, а тут я засомневался. В тексте были отрывки из книги, а именно: «Нам нужны данные, чтобы сделать выводы» — подчеркивает Херцинг — «На других планетах быстро это сделать будет весьма трудно..."
Корректор после слов автора (перед вторым тире) убрала запятую. Разве это правильно? Или я путаю с оформлением диалога?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По известным правилам данное предложение должно быть оформлено так: «Нам нужны данные, чтобы сделать выводы, — подчеркивает Херцинг. — На других планетах быстро это сделать будет весьма трудно..."

Answer (score 1):

Если это действительно диалог, как вы пишете, а не речь одного лица, то правильно так:

"Нам нужны данные, чтобы сделать выводы», — подчеркивает Херцинг. «На других планетах быстро это сделать будет весьма трудно..."

Хотя на диалог не похоже.

Answer (score 0):

А что из себя представляет фрагмент *«Нам нужны данные, чтобы сделать выводы... На других планетах быстро это сделать будет весьма трудно...»*? Если это две части оного высказывания (авторства некоего Херцинга) то оформление несколько странно, что с запятой, что без. Тут вернее будет то, что сказал [[@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799) (хотя это не единственный вариант). 
А если действительно действительно диалог (даже моделируемый - цитата одного автора "отвечает" цитате другого), то см. [[@tat](/users/3588/tat)](/users/3588/tat).

Answer (score 0):

Это явно не диалог,поэтому полностью согласна с первым вариантом ответа.